# django install errors on MAC OSX - Yosemite

Tags: python, django, macos

I am using Pip to install django on MAC OSX Yosemite and I am running into the following errors during the install process

```
_^[root:~/development]# pip2.6 install django
Downloading/unpacking django
  Downloading Django-1.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2MB): 6.2MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: django
Compiling /private/tmp/pip_build_root/django/django/contrib/admin/filters.py ...
SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('/private/tmp/pip_build_root/django/django/contrib/admin/filters.py', 298, 36, '        self.date_params = {k: v for k, v in params.items()\n'))

Compiling /private/tmp/pip_build_root/django/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py ...
SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('/private/tmp/pip_build_root/django/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py', 281, 38, "        if not (set(ordering) & {'pk', '-pk', pk_name, '-' + pk_name}):\n"))

Compiling /private/tmp/pip_build_root/django/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py ...
SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('/private/tmp/pip_build_root/django/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py', 94, 40, '    return {hasher.algorithm: hasher for hasher in get_hashers()}\n'))
```

The installation reports that it completed fine.

```
Compiling /private/tmp/pip_build_root/django/django/views/debug.py ...
SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('/private/tmp/pip_build_root/django/django/views/debug.py', 64, 56, '                cleansed = {k: cleanse_setting(k, v) for k, v in value.items()}\n'))

Successfully installed django
Cleaning up...
```

There are two Python versions installed on the MAC client, python2.6 and python2.7.

Does anyone have a clue as to why this could be happening? I am running the pip install command as root.

Comment: Dictionary comprehensions were added in Python 2.7. What's the output of `pip2.6 -V`?

Comment: ^_^[root:~]# pip2.6 -V
pip 1.5.6 from /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.6.egg (python 2.6)

Comment: Alright so it looks like you're trying to install Django using pip/python 2.6. Django 1.8 is only supported in [python 2.7+](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mike suggested, Django 1.8 is only supported in **2.7 and 3.2, 3.3, 3.4**. You'll need to use a newer version of Python, or just install the older version of Django:

```
pip install django==1.4
```